# How to reward someone after bounty has finished?

Tags: support, bounty

I started a bounty and waited until it ended, after that I read the answers and picked the best one, marked it as accepted. But now I'm not sure if an author of the answer has been rewarded? And possibly how can I reward them if they weren't? There is no button to do this and no record in my notifications other than -50 points for starting the bounty.

Comment: As far as I know it can take a bit of time until the bounty has been "paid out".

Comment: Will I see it somewhere in the records then? Is it okay I evaluated answers after bounty ended?

Comment: You will see a blue box under the score of the awarded answer showing the awarded bounty. When you mean with evaluated that you up-/down-voted and/or accepted the answer, then no, I don't think that interferes negatively here.

Comment: If you're talking [about this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57629313/revisions), it expired. You can only award the bounty for 8 days (there's a 24 hour grace period, after which it goes to an answer matching some criteria, or expires if none do). Accepting the answer is one criteria, but you did so after the bounty expired. So essentially, the rep is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood how bounties work. You said you waited until after the bounty ended, but that clears the bounty. From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty/):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

The answer you accepted [only got upvoted and accepted today](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58316067/timeline), meaning it didn't qualify for the > 2 score criteria. What this means is that no posts qualified for the bounty, and since you didn't manually award it, it wasn't awarded to anyone, and it expired. Including the grace period, you need to award it manually within 8 days, or have one or more answers matching the auto-awarding criteria. Otherwise, it's gone.

You can't award an expired bounty because it's exactly that - expired. Gone if you prefer. You can also tell that it wasn't awarded because none of the answers have a blue box underneath the voting buttons saying `+<bounty amount>`. If you're wondering where the rep went, it's gone. And no, [you won't get it back](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty/). You can start another bounty and award that manually if you really want to give the answerer a bounty, but that sets the minimum bounty to 100 rep IIRC.

Comment: I don't mind loosing my rep because of this bug (or a feature as you say), but this approach doesn't seem really good and intuitive to me. I started the bounty to find an answer to a general issue and also to reward the author of the best answer. I hoped this is the reason bounties exist in StackOverflow, but now I'm unsure. I don't have time to check daily how the bounty is going, and possibly I also forgot about it. StackOverflow also haven't mentioned the bounty is coming to an end. Now I want to award the author of the answer with 50 points. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Another thing is, that it ended just 5 days back, so I don't really understand this: `If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period)`. 7 days within what? I would understand the grace period to be 7 days, because that period seems logical to me to find out bounty ended, read the answers, try the answers, find out which are working, which are best written and decide, who should be rewarded.

Comment: 7 days within creating the bounty. The grace period is 24 hours. Which means if it ended 5 days ago, you made the bounty ~13 days ago (not accounting for timezones and date rounding). You're right it's unintiutive, and it's not obvious that's the way it works. And to answer your question - no, you can't award one of 50 rep to that answer. For whatever reason, there's an incremental increase (so you can't create a 50 rep bounty on a question twice).

Comment: And is there any other way to send 50 reputation to someone? (I know this is far from my original question)

Comment: Eh, you could award it on another question if you absolutely want, but I highly recommend you make sure both the question and the answer are good before you create the bounty.

Comment: I'm loosing my mind: I started a new 100 point one, (s)he deserves it. I've chosen I want to reward existing (and accepted) answer, but the bounty does not allow me to give the reputation right now. I have to wait 24 hours. This is like a hell, just in StackOverflow's interpretation. Why does it ask me for the reason, when it won't accept it?

Comment: Never using bounties again, this is such a poorly designed feature by SO developers (Has it always been like that?)

Comment: Can't tell if it's always been like that, but it has been for the past 3 or so years, at least if my memory is correct.

Comment: @aleskva the main purpose of bounty is limited-time advertising, so putting a bounty and awarding it so soon is also the opposite of the goal. (And also to minimize potential abuse)

Comment: @AndrewT. So why when starting a bounty I can choose an option "I want to award an existing answer"? This option should be either supported or completely removed from the choice.

Comment: @aleskva because it's the only reason that allow a user to award the bounty to an existing answer, and yes, it's supported, but the user still needs to wait the minimum time for the bounty to be eligible to award. Just put the bounty and set a reminder to award it...